# Javascript eclipse proposal not showing onclick

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse

Ok, i'm new at using eclipse because i'm learning Java for school, but i had a problem yesterday, trying to follow some book tutorial, i saw that javascript context did not show every method usable by a form for example:

I have an html button like that

```
<input type="button" value="Year" id="Button" />
```

when i try to write this

```
document.getElementById("button").o
```

and hit the ctrl+space for get the purposal, i didn't get nothing, i want it to show me the onclick function of the button...
Why eclipse didn't show me that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40345457/eclipse-neon-content-assist-has-no-proposals-for-javascript/41359420#41359420)
here is a solution in another question I've suggested,if it doesn't work,check
window---preferences---javascript---content assist
make sure all the relative setting is been set,and in the
window---preferences---javascript---content assist
you can try to tick all the content assist proposal to have a try

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has a bug in the versions mayors to eclipse mars, its doesnt work the content assist for javascript.

You can use instead, the tern plugin, it has the autocompletion for jquery, js, bootstrap and more frameworks :)

1. for intall it, go to **help** -> **eclipse market**
   [img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JhSz.png)
2. then in the text box put "tern", and install this option
   [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWwRm.png)
3. restart eclipse IDE and follow this tutorial: https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Getting-Started
4. when you finish the tutorial you can see the sugestion works
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZIqL.png)

PD. my english is a little poor but i hope that you understand me