# Eclipse Neon Content Assist has no proposals for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, eclipse, autocomplete, content-assist, eclipse-neon

Bottom Line Up Front: Eclipse Neon content assist (Ctrl+space) does not offer any proposals for my JavaScript code.

[image: Screenshot of empty content assist (ctrl+space)]

Here is what I've checked so far:

1. JSDT has been installed
2. "JavaScript resources" include ECMASciptBuilt-In Library, ECMA 3 Browser Support Library, jQuery
3. The project's Include path has ECMAScipt Built-In Library, ECMA 3 Browser Support Library, jQuery, and JavaScript Web Project support
4. Eclipse's JavaScript Content Assist is enabled and includes Basic proposals, Other JavaScript Proposals, Template Proposals, and word proposals.
5. I changed the content assist from ctrl+space to ctrl+0 to check whether ctrl+space had been hijacked
6. Content assist DOES work with regular Java (in a different project)
7. I tried reset to defaults under Content Assist > Advanced
8. JavaScript facet is selected for the project
9. .js files and .jsp files are stored in folders that are under folders that are designated as source folders in the project properties under JavaScript > Include Path
10. This is also an issue in Mars 2.
11. I've run through the steps listed here for configuring content assist: http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/using_javascript_content_assist.htm

The content assist isn't even proposing functions that are defined within the same .js file. How can I get Eclipse's content assist to propose elements correctly?

Comment: I know I'm probably not much helpful, but I'll still say it: Eclipse has been the absolutely most miserable experience when developing JavaScript. It's just so bad all around and I never even managed to make it behave better - no matter what plugins I tried it seemed to just ignore anything to do with JS. The "best" thing I managed to configure is to stop the content assist, since it would regularly freeze the entire IDE for upwards of 10 seconds only to give me that "No proposal" dialog. When I hadn't even asked for it. If you can make it behave - great, but you can also look at alternatives.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions for alternatives.  What do you recommend?

Comment: _Sublime Text_ is widely used, although I've not actually used it much. It has a paid version which is supposed to be really awesome and some people swear to it. _Atom_ is open source editor made _by_ GitHub and it is trying to be a free _Sublime_. It has lots of extensions for it and is rather good, although, some plugins should be included by default, if you ask me. _Brackets_ is free and made by Adobe (of all people). I really liked it when I was using it. _Notepad++_ is actually really good out of the box in Windows. _WebStorm_ is supposed to be one of the top but it's also paid.

Comment: Awesome.  I'll give those a shot, too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have the same problem and it seems to be a known bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=504057

Comment: Still seems to be broken in Oxygen ... can anybody confirm ... I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: Still broken in Eclipse IDE 2018-09, In a JS file there are no suggestion and in an html file "Ctrl+Space" doesn't even open the content assist and it also doesn't auto-open after a ".", even though I enabled it in the settings.

Comment: It does work in Mars.2 ("for PHP Developers") but not in any newer version. I tested 2018-09 "for PHP Developers" and Neon/Photon/2018-09 "for JavaScript and Web Developers". Win 10 (64bit) btw.

Comment: I can confirm that it works with Mars. That was the latest one that worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

+1 not working in Eclipse Neon. As an alternative you may try Netbeans 8. Javascript is working good there. I don't know what happened to Eclipse but php and Js support is poor.

P.S. Just downloaded Eclipse Mars - can confirm that it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've met this situation before,and then I found that if the js file is in a **"normal java project"**,then it won't come uip with content assist,but if the js file is in a **"dynamic web project"**,then the content assist just work well,hope it will help.

Comment: **Nope**. JavaScript contest assist isn't working at all in the neon release. I tried `static web project`, `dynamic web project` and even `javascript project`, but when I pressed `window.` there was no content assist in either code (and also tried ctrl+space, still none).

Comment: Finally, I had to revert back to mars release, in which its still working.