# Eclipse for PHP Developers - Javascript Content Assist and Tasks Not Working

Tags: javascript, eclipse, content-assist, eclipse-2020-03

I'm using **Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers** Version 2020-03 (4.15.0) on Windows 10 Home, 64-bit.

When I create a **JavaScript project** (or create a PHP project and convert it to a JavaScript project) and edit a .js file or type JavaScript code between  tags in an .html file, **Content Assist is not giving any suggestions** for built-in JavaScript objects or methods, and **task tags (like TODO) are not showing** in the Tasks view.

Content Assist will suggest functions, variables, objects, and methods created in whatever .js file is currently being edited, but it won't suggest any built-in JavaScript objects or methods unless they've already been used in the file (in which case it treats them as user-defined). ECMAScript Built-In Library, JavaScript Web Project Support, and ECMA 3 Browser Support Library are all included in the project's JavaScript Include Path. I can expand the Libraries under "JavaScript Resources" in the project tree and double-click on any of the entries to open the .js files that contain the definitions for the built-in objects and methods, but Content Assist doesn't suggest any of them when I type and press ctrl+space.

The Tasks view shows task tags in .php, .css, and .html files, but not in .js files. If I add a task tag in a .js file (like "/*TODO Fix this*/") the tag is highlighted correctly (syntax highlighting in .js files works), but it doesn't register as a task (the task icon doesn't appear in the gutter to the left of the line number the way it does in .html, .css, and .php files).

I've been searching for solutions for hours but everything I find either doesn't work, says to change a setting that's already set correctly, or doesn't apply to this version of Eclipse.

I tried using an older version of Eclipse (Oxygen.3a) and it does exactly the same thing, so I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong?

**EDIT:** Some answers for older versions of Eclipse that I wasn't able to find on my own showed up after I posted this (such as [Eclipse: Content Assist not showing suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53635280/)). I tried downloading an even older version of Eclipse, Mars.2, and everything is working correctly in that version. Are the issues in Eclipse 2020.3 just "bugs"?