# Eclipse for PHP Developers 2020-06 - Is There Any Way to Show Javascript Task in Tasks View?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-2020-06

I'm using Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers Version 2020-06 (Includes Incubating Components) (4.16.0) on Windows 10 Home, 64-bit, installed using the Windows 64-bit installation file from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/installer.

Is there any way to have task tags (like TODO) in .js files show up in the Tasks view? In this version of Eclipse the task filter doesn't even list "JavaScript" as an option and there are no JavaScript settings in Preferences. Task tags work in .html, .css, and .php files but not in .js files.

UPDATE: I've switched to version 2020-12 (4.18.0) and JavaScript task tags are working by default in this version.

Comment: Sounds like that version doesn't include the Javascript support. You can install it from Help > Install New Software.

Comment: @greg-449 In the PHP Eclipse IDE package 2020-06 JavaScript support is [no longer via JSDT, but via Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=561624). Maybe the task tag scanner is part of JSDT and therefore now missing the Eclipse PHP IDE.

Comment: You already asked that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62399761/6505250

Comment: In the Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers 2020-06 the JavaScript support was changed from [JSDT](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-web-developer-tools-0) to [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper). Does installing JSDT fix your issue? If yes, please report it as feature request to Eclipse Wild Web Developer.

Comment: @howlger Yes, this version includes JavaScript support by default using the Wild Web Developer plugin. I don't know if I'm just missing something, but I can't find any settings for the plugin, or for JavaScript, anywhere. I can't find a place to create templates or add to the JavaScript build path, either. I could never get task tags in .js files to show up in previous versions of Eclipse that used JSDT, but I could at least find the settings in Preferences>JavaScript. I've spent more time in the last week trying to get Eclipse to work than I have actually working on my project >.<

Comment: @Ossolox JSDT and Wild Web Developer offer JavaScript support in different ways. If you don't want to change anything and stick to your current way of working, just install JSDT in addition.

Comment: @howlger I installed JSDT and now there's a "Client-Side JavaScript" section under Preferences>Web>HTML Files with the settings that were under Preferences>JavaScript in previous versions, but there's no JavaScript Editor and none of the settings are used. But I could never get JavaScript content assist or task tags to work in 2020-03 using JSDT anyway (that's what my previous question was about). At least content assist works with WWD. But in addition to no task tags, I can't create or use templates in .js files. There must be settings somewhere, I just don't know where to look.

Comment: @Ossolox You say that there is no JavaScript editor, but I have already used it. You are talking about different things. Which one is the most important to you? How can the important one reproduced? Please edit your question and add a detailed step-by-step instructions on how to reproduce the issue (don't leave out anything, even if it seems obvious to you).

Comment: @howlger I edited the question to include the installation file I used. There's nothing to do to reproduce the issue - I installed the program and the JavaScript task tag functionality is not there. I was just hoping someone would know if there was a way to enable it. I discovered the other issues after asking and would create other questions for them. And the only right-click Open With options are Generic Text Editor (the default for .js files, which WWD uses) and Text Editor. The "JavaScript Editor" option from previous Eclipse versions is not there, even after installing JSDT.

Comment: The "JavaScript Editor" is intentionally not there in 2020-06. Its language support has been exceeded by what's in WWD for a while now, so it's a better editor for JavaScript. Unfortunately, WWD hasn't placed much emphasis on functionality outside of the editor, for any language. It's unclear when Task Tags actually stopped working, but it was likely during one of its internal compiler changes (it went through a few after the publicized "reboot").

Comment: Does the following answer solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62756966/6505250

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (in Eclipse version 2020-09 (4.17.0)):

1. Go to Window->Preferences.
2. Go to Web->JavaScript
3. "Task Tags in JavaScript can be configured here" <- click this link
4. Check the "Enable searching for Task Tags" checkbox
5. Click Apply and Close

Comment: Thanks Drew. As I said in my original post, I was using 4.16.0, and there were no JavaScript settings available in Preferences at all in that version.